# Add random number of key-value pair to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

My question is how can I add random number of the **{(name, f), (parameters, []})** object to my dictionary with a loop iteration (I see a loop as only way to solve it). 
In my example I have only 1 finding specified, but what if I want to have several (random number in a range)?
I have an array of *f's* and relevant *parameters*, so I want to have different number of findings each time I'm running the code.

```
"findings": [{ #constructor for BSON
    "name": f,
    "parameters": [parameters, parameters2, parameters3]
}, {..
}]
```

Comment: so `f` and relevant parameters come from another list?

Comment: List comprehension? `[{"name": f, "parameters": ps} for (f, ps) in whatever_produces_names_and_paramters]`?

Comment: yes, definitely. I have a function to pick random f and relevant parameters, but have no idea how to insert it in the dictionary, but not in manual way.

Comment: @chepner, won't work. I have to pre-define random number of f's first and only then insert them into a dict.

Comment: It would help if you specify exactly *how* you are predefining the data.

Comment: @chepner I have an array of f (refers to finding "name") and a functions which grabs relevant parameter to f (parameter, parameter2 and parameter3 are dictionaries too). What I want to do, is pick a random number of findings from a list and insert the data inside my dict.

Comment: Put a *clear* description of that (preferably with code) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following. I am assuming you want a random number of `name` `f` (likely `f` is a `str`) findings with their associated `parameters` (a `list`) appended as a `dict` to a `list` (which is the value part of a dictionary with key `findings`). I am also assuming that you have a function `get_params` that take an `f` (name?) argument and returns a `list` of parameters.

```
import random

# ...
# get a random number of f's from f_list (your list of f's)
# NOTE: don't get more than you have in the list
max_num_f = min(10, len(f_list))
num_f = random.randint(0, max_num_f)
# get an initial index to take a slice from your f_list
index = random.randint(0, len(f_list) - num_f)

# iterate over slice of f's chosen, get params and add to dict
for f in f_list[index : index+num_f]:
    # if findings key is missing, add it
    if 'findings' not in findings_dict:
        findings_dict['findings'] = []
    # add the findings dict to the list
    findings_dict['findings'].append({'name' : f, 'parameters' : get_params(f)})
```